# cancel parallel for when result found without checking the rest of iteration?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to write a c++ function that checks for even numbers inside an array, but I want to do it in parallel with Openmp; if there is an even number inside the array, the function stops all other threads from running, returns true, and exits immediately.
So the function checks for an even number, and at any index where it finds an even number, it returns true and exits immediately without checking for the rest of the iterations. Any thread that finds the even number returns true, stops the other thread, and exits.

when I tried to use omp cancel for I got this error:

error: orphaned 'cancel' construct
| #pragma omp cancel for
|

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

bool checkIfAnyEven(int arr[], int n)
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

bool par_checkIfAnyEven(int arr[], int n)
{
    bool flag = false;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

bool good_checkIfAnyEven(int arr[], int n)
{
    bool flag = false;
    bool flag2 = false;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(|| \
                                   : flag2)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            flag2 = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag2)
    {
        flag = true;
#pragma omp cancel for
    }

    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 1000;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i < 990)
            arr[i] = 2 * i + 1;
        else
            arr[i] = 2 * i;
    }

    if (checkIfAnyEven(arr, n))
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";

    std::cout << endl;

    if (par_checkIfAnyEven(arr, n))
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";

    std::cout << endl;

    if (good_checkIfAnyEven(arr, n))
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";

}
```

Edit: after reading the comment of @PierU I added the cancel after the flag2 = true;

```cpp
bool par_checkIfAnyEven(int arr[], int n)
{
    bool flag = false;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            flag = true;
#pragma omp cancel for
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

when I compile with g++ -Wall -fopenmp I got this warning:

```
warning: 'cancel for' inside 'nowait' for construct
   31 | #pragma omp cancel for
      |                       ^
```

Comment: @kiner_shah but you can not have break or return inside parallel for. openmp does not support break or return inside parallel for.

Comment: Your `cancel` directive is outside of the parallel region, you should put it right after the line `flag2 = true`

Comment: please @PierU write the full answer. do i need to add only the cancel after flag2 = true, so I only need one flag variable?

Comment: Hi @PierU when I compile with g++ -Wall -fopenmp i got this warning warning: 'cancel for' inside 'nowait' for construct
    | #pragma omp cancel for

Comment: If you use two separate directives  `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for`, you will not receive any warnings. It is becuase `#pragma omp parallel for` is equivalent to  `#pragma omp parallel\n#pragma omp for nowait` .